# Writing a multiple question test in TOEFL

Tags: exam, auto-multiple-choice

I am writing a book and use book document class. I would like to write a multiple choice questions as in the following picture:
[image]

I have tried to use standard enumerate but there are two things I could not achieve, i.e.
1. The choice cannot be aligned to question,
2. The counter cannot be put into the parentheses.

Thank very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By loading the `enumitem` package, you will have full control on `label`s, `leftmargin`, etc. You can further specify to which list level your custom settings apply. For example, in your case you need to customize the second level of `enumerate`, so the setting `\setlist[enumerate,2]{<...>}` is used. You have also the option to use these settings locally within some scope of enumerate as you wish, or even create your own custom list style (see the [package documentation](http://ctan.asis.io/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more details).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\spce}{\underline{\hspace{.7in}} }
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\alph*),leftmargin=*,align=left}

\begin{enumerate}
\item One of the \spce Black poets in America, Lucy Terry, was a slave in Deerfield, Massachusetts
\begin{enumerate}
\item first
\item first was
\item first to
\item first has the
\end{enumerate}
\item One of the \spce Black poets in America, Lucy Terry, was a slave in Deerfield, Massachusetts
\begin{enumerate}
\item first
\item first was
\item first to
\item first has the
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. How to make the level 1 to \noindent from the left margin?

Comment: @FaisalMustafa  - The same `\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=*}`. See my edit, please.

Comment: Gorgeous...! I am a really newbie. Thanks for putting up with me.